# MFC C++ Ивент Выхода из приложения

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Есть ли какой-то ивент по-умолчанию, который отрабатывается при выходе из приложения, например, при нажатиии на крестик выхода?

Comment: WM_QUIT наверное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В MFC для этой цели переопределяют виртуальную функцию

```
virtual int ExitInstance();
```

в классе приложения, то есть в классе, производном от `CWinApp` или `CWinAppEx`. Эта функция и вызывается при выходе из приложения, неважно, каким образом этот выход инициирован. Обрабатывать сообщение `WM_QUIT` в MFC программах не нужно.